# How can I slice images and save them using PHP?

Tags: php, gd

How would I slice an image up into, say 9 separate slices (3x3), and then save each individual slice to a folder? I've read that I'll need to use GD to achieve this, but I'm a total novice with this library.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: take a look at ImageMagick http://www.imagemagick.org

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries which do exactly what you want:

- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4349-PHP-Slice-large-images-in-multiple-parts.html
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1804-PHP-Generate-HTML-to-present-images-divided-in-pieces.html

Comment: Thanks. However, I have already looked at one of these closely but am unable to see how to actually make the script write out all the slices to a folder so I don't have to save them all individually if i have, say 150 slices.

Comment: So, show your code and what you have tried so far with this libraries.